# How to write the conditional probability that an event occurs given no others do?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have $n$ independent and not mutually exclusive events $ M_{1}, M_{2},... M_{n} $. I am interested in the conditional probability that an event $ M_{i} $ occurs but none of the others do.

If $n=2$, then it's just $ P(M_{1} \mid \overline{M_{2}}) $ and $ P(M_{2} \mid \overline{M_{1}}) $, respectively. How can I write this in a general way for an unknown number of events?

Comment: $P(M_1 | \overline{M_2} \cap \cdots \cap \overline{M_n} )$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional probability that the $i$-th $M_\ast$ event occurs when the non-occurance of every other $M_\ast$ event is given, is denoted as:

$$\mathsf P\Big(M_i \;\Big\vert \;\bigcap_{\substack{j\in\{1..n\} \\ j\neq i}} \overline{M_j}\Big)= \mathsf P\left(M_i \;\middle\vert\; \overline{M_1}\cap\cdots\cap\overline{M_{i-1}}\cap\overline{M_{i+1}}\cap\cdots\cap\overline{M_n}\right)$$